# Changing language typing direction using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to change the typing direction of text using selenium Python to right to left.

The normal Key sequence in the keyboard for that is CTRL+SHIFT (both right).

I have tried the following:

```
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

   def testLangDirChange(self):      
        self.driver.get("http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html")
        XPathTB='//textarea[@name="t"]'
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, XPathTB)))
        TB=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPathTB)
        TB.click()
        actionChains=ActionChains(self.driver)
        actionChains.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

I see the correct Key sequence in the tester, but the typing direction does not change (I still get left to right).

I also tried:

```
firefoxProfile.native_events_enabled = False
firefoxProfile.set_preference("intl.accept_languages", 'he-IL')
```

But it did not help.

(You must have a right to left keyboard layout such as Hebrew in order to test this)

**UPDATE 1**:

I just enabled the following checkboxes on the testing site: modifiers, DOM 3, old DOM 3 and compared the two outputs. what I see is that in the selenium typing it is location=1 and in the keyboard test it is location=2.

Maybe Selenium types LEFT SHIFT when I do Keys.SHIFT(although the key LEFT SHIFT is separately specified in Keys)?

**UPDATE 2:**

I found inside the module selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys the following:

```
SHIFT        = '\ue008'
LEFT_SHIFT   = SHIFT
```

so they are indeed defined the same. how do I specify RIGHT SHIFT in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running an AutoIt script using:

os.system(r'"C:\path\changeLangDir.exe"')

with the content:

```
send("{RCTRL}{RSHIFT}")
```

also another solution is to set the dir="ltr" tag to dir="rtl"

using:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[arguments.length-1].dir = 'rtl';", TB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure your WebDriver can send commands to OS level, I think what it does is to operate within the browser only. Instead why don't you try inputting the other language directly with sendKeys(otherLang) ?

Answer (score 0):

after alot of search i found solution for changing language for chromedriver and using python. i'm using linux.this ma work for you..

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google\ 
Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
prefs = {
"translate_whitelists": {"fr": "en", "de": "en", 'it': 'en', 'no': 'en', 'es': 
'en', 'sv': 'en', 'nl': 'en',
'da': 'en', 'pl': 'en', 'fi': 'en', 'cs': 'en'},
"translate": {"enabled": "true"}
 }
 options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Comment: Let me know if any confusion

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer try to explain it a little bit. If there are previous answers, then show the Pros of yours.